# re-order x-axis time series data

Tags: r, plot

I have the following data:

```
month   eD_data eD_model
1   10.6    10.57456047
1   10.6    10.56613913
1   10.6    10.55792205
1   10.6    10.54991164
1   10.6    10.54211029
1   10.6    10.53452031
1   10.6    10.52714394
1   10.6    10.51998337
1   10.6    10.51304073
1   10.6    10.50631807
2   10.4    10.41738606
2   10.4    10.41613442
2   10.4    10.41513148
2   10.4    10.41437754
2   10.4    10.41387281
2   10.4    10.41361745
2   10.4    10.41361153
2   10.4    10.41385505
2   10.4    10.41434794
2   10.4    10.45139153
2   10.4    10.45580457
3   10.2    10.47581204
3   10.2    10.48139532
3   10.2    10.48720795
3   10.2    10.49324822
3   10.2    10.49951433
3   10.2    10.50600444
3   10.2    10.51271661
3   10.2    10.51964885
3   10.2    10.52679912
3   10.2    10.53416529
3   10.2    10.63854333
3   10.2    10.64849527
```

There are still data for other months up to 12. But here is short cut. What I want to have is that making a plot but the x-axis, i.e. month, starts from July (7)
Here is my code:

```
a<-factor(mydat$month, levels=c("7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6")
plot(eD_data~a, data=mydat) 
lines(eD_model~a, data=mydat)
Here what I got
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the line starts also from july and being continuous?
Thanks!

Comment: After you turn `month` into a factor, sort your data by `month` before plotting it.  `mydat$month=factor(mydat$month, levels=c(7:12,1:6)); mydat = mydat[order(mydat$month), ]; plot(eD_data ~ month, data=mydat)`.

Comment: @eipi10: doing by your way just returns the data to origin, it will starts from January (i.e. 1). As indicated I want the x-axis start from 7. In the plot(eD_data~month) this works fine, but then lines(eD_model~month) is not working as it seem constant within a month.

Comment: See example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data frame needs to be sorted based on the ordering of the x-axis values. Otherwise, `lines` will have to backtrack when a data frame row with a higher x-value appears after a data frame row with a lower x-value.

```
# Fake data
set.seed(4865)
dat = data.frame(month=1:12, values=rnorm(12))
```

Set ordering of month to start in July and "wrap around" to June:

```
dat$month=factor(dat$month, levels=c(7:12,1:6))
```

Plot with rows in original order: We've set the factor order to start in July, so that's what we get on the x-axis. However, the rows of the data frame start with January. `lines` just places a line from point to point in the order the data appears in the data frame, so the line starts in January and has to backtrack to get from June to July:

```
plot(values ~ month, data=dat)
lines(values ~ month, data=dat)
```

[image]

Sort rows by `month`: Now the rows of the data frame appear with the same order as the factor `month`, and all is well:

```
dat = dat[order(dat$month), ]

plot(values ~ month, data=dat)
lines(values ~ month, data=dat)
```

[image]

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much for your help.